# TypeError: Network request failed. How to Append Multiple Images in Array to formData properly. react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, append, multipartform-data, form-data

I am new to react native. I am trying to append multiple images in array to formData. like this

```
 formData.append('application_copy_file', 
          [{
            uri: this.state.ApplicationCopy,
            name: 'upload_application_copy.jpg',
            type: 'image/*'
          },
          {
            uri: this.state.ApplicationCopy1,
            name: 'upload_application_copy1.jpg',
            type: 'image/*'
          },
          {
            uri: this.state.ApplicationCopy2,
            name: 'upload_application_copy2.jpg',
            type: 'image/*'
          },
        ]);
```

But when I append like this. I am getting error like this when I submit form = [TypeError: Network request failed]

And when I upload only one like this =

```
formData.append('application_copy_file', 
           {
            uri: this.state.ApplicationCopy,
            name: 'upload_application_copy.jpg',
            type: 'image/*'
          }
          );
```

then its working fine but saying = count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable. from server response.text.
please help .

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
formData.append('application_copy_file[0]', 
       {
        uri: this.state.ApplicationCopy,
        name: 'upload_application_copy.jpg',
        type: 'image/*'
      }
      );
formData.append('application_copy_file[1]', 
       {
        uri: this.state.ApplicationCopy1,
        name: 'upload_application_copy.jpg',
        type: 'image/*'
      }
      );
```

if i assume everyhing in your state is just for uploading.

you can do,

```
Object.keys(this.state).forEach((item, i) => {
      formData.append(`application_copy_file[${i}]`, 
       {
        uri: this.state[item],
        name: this.state[item] + '.jpg',
        type: 'image/*'
      }
      );
})
```

Comment: please how do i add this with for each loop. please

Comment: i edited, please also accept answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pass the images array so put the array in `JSON.stringify(your images array)`